# C++ keyboard hook - what does the parameter nCode mean?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, hook, keylogger

I am looking to write a keyboard hook for a c++ project. I found some code but dont want to use it without fully understanding it:

```
HHOOK _hook;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int ncode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if(ncode>=HC_ACTION)
    {
        if((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) || (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            DWORD dwMsg = 1;
            dwMsg += kbdStruct.scanCode << 16;
            dwMsg += kbdStruct.flags << 24;
            char key[16];
            GetKeyNameText(dwMsg,key,15);
            
            if((GetKeyNameState(VK_CAPITAL)& 0x0001) == 0)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<10)key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
                ReturnKeyPressed(key);
            }
            else
            {
                ReturnKeyPressed(key);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}
void SetHook()
{
    _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH__KEYBOARD_LL,HookCallback,Null,0);
}
```

I dont understand what nCode is here. And where do the other parameters come from?
Greeting from an absolute C++ beginner :).

Comment: You can find about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644975(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, `nCode` tells you whether the `wParam` and `lParam` contain valid data or not.  If `nCode` is `HC_ACTION` (0), then they do, otherwise they do not.  This is clearly stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)):

> - *nCode* [in]
>   Type: `int`
>
>   A code the hook procedure uses to determine how to process the message. **If *nCode* is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the `CallNextHookEx` function without further processing** and should return the value returned by `CallNextHookEx`. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
>   > HC_ACTION
>   > 0
>   >
>   > **The `wParam` and `lParam` parameters contain information about a keyboard message.**
> - *wParam* [in]
>   Type: `WPARAM`
>
>   The identifier of the keyboard message. This parameter can be one of the following messages: [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(v=vs.85)), [`WM_KEYUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281(v=vs.85)), [`WM_SYSKEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646286(v=vs.85)), or [`WM_SYSKEYUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646287(v=vs.85)).
> - *lParam* [in]
>   Type: `LPARAM`
>
>   A pointer to a [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644967(v=vs.85)) structure.